How to center the form input type=file element
I am having problem figuring out how to center the input type="file" element. It has the width of 100% and the form has the width of 30% of the whole screen.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Face Recognition</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <% if(locals.myresp){ %>
        <img src="<%= myresp %>" alt="processed_img">
        <a href="<%= myresp %>" download="<%= filename %>"><button>Download</button></a>
    <%} else{ %>
        <h1>Face Recognition</h1>
    <% } %>
    <form action="/face-read" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="image">Choose Your Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="imagefile" accept="image/*">
        <input type="submit" value="Generate">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

body{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

a{
    background-color: white;
}
h1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

form{
    width: 30%;
    height: 20vh;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 20vh;
}

form label {
    width: 100vw;
}

form input {
    width: 100%;
}

[type="submit"]{
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

I don't want to wrap this in some kind of container or something I just want a css property like text-align to center the items which is inside the input type="file". I tried using margin-left but it just moves the whole input to right which I don't want.
